# Not using await Task.Delay(x) (x>0) makes UI thread freeze

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

I have this function that bruteforces GUIDs to calculate IDs (GUIDs are hash calculations of the ID, so reversing the procedure can't be done by nothing else but bruteforcing through 2^32-1 (yes, that's right) possible IDs.

I used `await Task.Delay(1);` to "refresh" the UI thread so everything looks natural, however this slows down the process too much, but if I were to use `await Task.Delay(0);` the whole app would freeze and i wouldn't know the current progress of the search (shown as the `2 IProgress`s for the progress bar.

```
    async public Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetSteamIds(Dictionary<string,string> GUIDs, IProgress<UInt32> progress, IProgress<double> progress2)
    {
        List<string> Progress = new List<string>();
        foreach(string GUID in GUIDs.Keys)
        {
            Progress.Add(GUID);
        }
        for (;Iteration <= UInt32.MaxValue;Iteration++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(0);
            string guid = CalculateGUID(MinAcc+Iteration);
            if(GUIDs.ContainsKey(guid))
            {
                GUIDs[guid] = Convert.ToString((Int64)(MinAcc + Iteration));
            }

            progress.Report(Iteration);
            progress2.Report((1.0 * Iteration / UInt32.MaxValue * 100));

            if(Progress.Count==0)
            {
                if (progress2 != null)
                {
                    progress2.Report(100);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return GUIDs;
    }
```

I do not know how to mitigate this and even though my whole method is async, and the call is async, it still sits on the "UI thread" and I don't know how to work around this.

Naturally, I would appreciate a good answer that works, but I would also appreciate some elaboration to how this all works. I've read quite a bit of articles but none really explained it to me in a way for me to understand everything.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything else asynchronous in nature about your function. Slapping `async` on it doesn't magically make it asynchronous. It needs to actually *do* something asynchronously. All awaiting `Task.Delay()` is doing is yielding control so that other stuff can update, instead of being locked in a loop. You should look into a dedicated thread or BackgroundWorker for something that's somewhat heavy-lifting, like this.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `BackgroundWorker` and considering whether you can adapt your approach to using it instead.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is effectively obsolete. Use Task.Run() and Dispatcher

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot thank you for the explanation. I actually expected that by making it async and moving it to another class will make it run on a new thread.. unfortunately I don't know hoe to utilize either backgroundworker or dedicated threads (sorry for typos, I'm mobile now, going home from work)

Comment: noone amused by the fact he's "bruteforcing" guids? ok then...

Comment: @Dbl these are BattlEye GUIDs that are logged in DayZ and ArmA3. Goal of this project is to help admins ban cheaters by their steamId. Unfortunately GUID is MD5 byte hash from the 64bit SteamID thus can't be reversed.

Comment: @DethoRhyne your program would take years to get through all guids. I'd recommend you to have a look at rainbow tables instead

Comment: @Dbl - I didn't understand the full narrative, but parts of the question indicated he's brute-forcing `something` to produce GUIDs - and that problem space is apparently 2^32 (quote from question), not 2^124 (assuming we know what type of GUIDs we're aiming for)

Comment: @Dbl it wouldn't Steam has the range of 4 billion users, but only about 100,200 million are used. Program searches for GUIDs based on the input and there's a control that breaks the loop once all GUIDs have their matching SteamID

Answer (score 4):

Adding the `async` keyword to a method doesn't actually make the method asynchronous, it just means that you're allowed to use the `await` keyword inside of the method.  You've written an entirely synchronous CPU bound method and just tagged the method as `async`, making it still just a synchronous CPU bound method, and calling a synchronous CPU bound method from the UI thread is going to block the UI thread, preventing other UI actions from taking place.

Adding in an `await Task.Delay(1)` is making your method still do all of its long running CPU bound work in the UI thread, it's just stopping every once in a while to move to the end of the line, allowing other operations to run.  Not only is this slowing down your work, it also means that the UI thread isn't able to perform other UI operations the vast majority of the time as this process is using up so much of its time.

The solution is to simply not do the long running CPU bound work in the UI thread at all, and to offload that work to another thread.

Since this method of your isn't *actually* asynchronous, you should remove the `async` keyword from the method (and change the return type accordingly).  When you *call* this method, if you happen to need to do so from the UI thread, simply wrap it in a call to `Task.Run` which will offload it to a thread pool thread.  If that UI operation need to do work after it has completed with the result, then *that UI operation* can `await` the result of `Task.Run`, and *that* method should be marked as `async`, because it really is doing its work asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

Don't run the task on the UI thread.

You could call it like this:

```
var myTask = Task.Run(() => GetSteamIds(...));
```

And keep a reference to `myTask` somewhere so you can test `myTask.IsCompleted` to see when it's done.

Or, you can use ContinueWith to automatically run some other code when the Task completes. For example:

```
var myTask = Task.Run(() => GetSteamIds(...)).ContinueWith(() => {
    //do something here now that the task is done
  }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` is to make sure that the continuation code runs on the UI thread (since you will likely want to update the UI with the results).

With this usage, there is no need for your method to be asynchronous at all (it does not need to return Task<>).

Or use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as suggested in the comments.

Comment: this actually seems like a good idea, BUT i dont know how to implement it.. could you write a simple example with a for loop inside the function.. and lets say, how would you finish the task when it's completed?

Comment: I updated my answer. But you will probably have to modify it for your specific case.

Comment: By using your solution I get "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." error almost instantly, also ContinueWith refused to build with 0 parameters for some reason..
Could this be because I use Progress and not IProgress?

Comment: I replaced Progress with IProgress and everything is working now, but it's jamming the UI thread again and the whole app freezes.. :/

Answer (score 3):

Your `GetSteamIds` method is entirely synchronous and CPU-bound, so it should have a synchronous signature:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetSteamIds(Dictionary<string,string> GUIDs, IProgress<UInt32> progress, IProgress<double> progress2);
```

Now, when you want to invoke this (synchronous, CPU-bound) method from the UI thread, use `await Task.Run` to run it on a threadpool thread and (asynchronously) get the result of the method:

```
var results = await Task.Run(() => GetSteamIds(guids, progress, progress2));
```

If you're using `Progress<T>`, then it will take care of handling progress updates on the UI thread for you; there's no need for the awkward `Dispatcher` or `Control.Invoke`.

On a side note, with a very tight CPU-bound loop like this, you may find your progress reports themselves will slow down your UI and degrade your user experience. In that case, consider using my [ObservableProgress](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/4248e50b4cb52b933c0d), an `IProgress<T>` implementation that throttles progress updates.

Answer (score -1):

when you call `await Task.Delay(1)` it will actually give back access to the UI thread because probably the problem is not in the method you are calling, it is in the call of the method.

So you should remove the Task.Delay() in the method and show us the call of the method so we can help you further

Comment: its a standard call. eg. output = await func(); I'm currently mobile and about 1 hr away from home and this is best of a,reply I can make atm

Comment: @DethoRhyne - yes, it's a standard call. It's purpose is to *delay* some activity. Is that what you want to do? If not, you're *abusing* this function.

Comment: Purpose is to call a function that will iterate 2^32 or less numbers. I wanted the app to do that asynchronously so UI gets updated with progress information.